# pass list<data> to custom adapter

Tags: java, android, twitter, getview

I have created a list for custom adapter by writing following code:

```
public class TweetListActivity extends ListActivity {

private ListView tweetListView;
private ArrayAdapter tweetItemArrayAdapter;
private final List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tweet_list);
    for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)

    {
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
        tweet.setTitle("A nice header for Tweet # " + i);
        tweet.setBody("Some random body text for the tweet # " + i);
        tweets.add(tweet);
    }
    tweetItemArrayAdapter = new TweetAdapter(this,tweets);

    setListAdapter(tweetItemArrayAdapter);
}
}
```

code for `TweetAdapter` is as below

```
public class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> 
{
    private List<Tweet> tweetslocal;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

public TweetAdapter(Activity activity, List<Tweet> tweets) {
    super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets);
    inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
    tweetslocal = tweets;
}

@Override
public Tweet getItem(int arg0) {
    return tweetslocal.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
    TextView tweetTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tweetTitle);
    Tweet tweet = tweetslocal.get(position);
    tweetTitle.setText(tweet.getTitle());
    TextView tweetBody = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tweetBody);
    tweetBody.setText(tweet.getBody());
    return row;
}
}
```

But, I am not getting the desired output. The list is showing all tweets with header 20 instead of increamental tweets from tweet1 to tweet 20.

Comment: where is your `TweetAdapter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

implemented

import java.io.Serializable;

in Tweet.java

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I see you already pass on the list of tweets to your `TweetAdapter`.

In `TweetAdapter`, declare a list of `Tweet`'s:

```
    private List<Tweet> tweets;
```

Then, make sure your constructor looks like this:

```
    public TweetAdapter(Context ctx, List<Tweet> tweets) {
        this.context = ctx; //Context == activity
        this.tweets = tweets;
    }
```

Now, in your `getView()`, you can do this:

```
final Tweet currentTweet = tweets.get(position);
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: i have also added the tweetadapter activity code. can you help me with that sir?

Comment: also after adding the constructor it gives me error
"There is no default constructor available in 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter'"

Answer (score 0):

Get tweets object like this if the array named tweets in your TweetAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    Tweet tweet = tweets.get(position);
    // TODO using tweet.
}
```

Do you mean this?